# Typo3 on Bluemix

Tags: typo3, ibm-cloud

Is it possible to run a Typo3 application on Bluemix?

I've already seen an approach to run a WordPress application on bluemix. But does some kind of service or integration exist to do the same with typo3?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Anything that relies on a persistent file system will not be a good fit for a CF app and would need the extra considerations that you've already brought up regarding WordPress deployments.